# Showing SearchWidget on left and opened on Actionbar(actionbar compat) when activity loads

Tags: searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I am new to android and working on an app like dictionary.I am using search view from actionbar compat for searching suggestion and it is working good.
The problem is I want the search view on left aligned(where title shows) on actionbar and opened when the activity loads which is ok with normal devices but on tab it looks right aligned.
I have tried all the combination of showAsAction="" and setIconified() and setIconifiedByDefault() but not getting the desired result.
I want to use the default search view not custom if it is possible. I have searched a lot for this.
Is there any way(or link) by which i can get the desired output.

```
    menu.xml:
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always">

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView  =(SearchView)enuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(mOnQueryTextListener);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
```

Thanks in advance...